# Why didn't C have a boolean data type prior to C99?

Tags: c, language-design, c99, c89

I realise you can just `#define` some integers, but why didn't C have a dedicated boolean data type before C99?

It's such a common occurence in programming and logic, I don't understand the absense of an explicit type and notation.

Comment: -1: What problem is solved by knowing the history of Kernighan's and Ritchie's implementation details of C?

Comment: @S.Lott - sorry, did I miss understand the purpose of StackOverflow?  Is this question not programming related?  From the FAQ: "this is a place for questions that can be answered."  "As long as your question is... detailed and specific, written clearly and simply, of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere."  What else did I miss?

Comment: @S.Lott i suspect you should remove chapter "Background and History" from your Python book.

Comment: @S.Lott Where's my -1? At least follow through on your snarkiness.

Comment: @S.Lott - It may not solve a specific problem *right now*, but I've found that understanding the design decisions has usually helped me gain a much better understanding of a language.

Comment: Having a bool type can give speed advantages in some area, because the compiler can make up the representation of it. It may assume that a bool  only ever has the LSB at 1 or 0, and all other bits at 0. So for instance when doing `return (int)!!some_boolean;` it can just move the boolean to the return value, while when some_boolean  is just an int, it has to branch if there is no special cpu instruction. And for `boolean = !boolean;` it doesn't need a branch either (as for int). It could just flip the LSB, for example.

Comment: There's a huge difference between history -- as facts -- and "why?" in this question.  The facts are clear.  The rationale is only known to Kernighan and Ritchie.  The best we can to is guess randomly for their rationale.  I don't like guessing, and -- absent their input -- the question is not answerable as asked.

Comment: I have to say that I find "Why doesn't language Foo have feature Bar?" questions to be intrinsically argumentative. In any case, the answer is the K&C doesn't have anything that it doesn't *need*. And an explicit Boolean type is a frill.

Comment: @S.Lott, C89 wasn't done by Kernighan and Ritchie. It was done by a committee. The rationale must be known to the committee members aswell.

Comment: @S. Lott: No need to guess; Ritchie left a trail in the historical record...

Comment: The more interesting question is why does C still not have a boolean data type without `#include <stdbool.h>`, which is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47821877/4284627

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you spend a little time in the library, you don't have to speculate.
Here are some statements taken from [Dennis Ritchie's paper on the evolution of C](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/docs/chistory.html). The context is that Dennis is building on Ken Thompson's language B, which was implemented on the very tiny PDP-7, a word-addressed machine.  Because of growing interest, the group got one of the very first PDP-11s.  Dennis writes,

> The advent of the PDP-11 exposed several inadequacies of B's semantic model. First, its character-handling mechanisms, inherited with few changes from BCPL, were clumsy: using library procedures to spread packed strings into individual cells and then repack, or to access and replace individual characters, began to feel awkward, even silly, on a byte-oriented machine.
>
> The B and BCPL model implied overhead in dealing with pointers: the language rules, by defining a pointer as an index in an array of words, forced pointers to be represented as word indices. Each pointer reference generated a run-time scale conversion from the pointer to the byte address expected by the hardware.
>
> For all these reasons, it seemed that a typing scheme was necessary to cope with characters and byte addressing, and to prepare for the coming floating-point hardware. Other issues, particularly **type safety and interface checking, did not seem as important then as they became later.**

(Emphasis mine.)

The paper goes on to describe Dennis's struggles to invent a new pointer semantics, to make arrays work, and to come to terms with this newfangled `struct` idea.  Notions of type safety and distinguishing Booleans from integers did not seem important until much later :-)

Answer (score 17):

C is actually little more than a higher-level assembly language. Yes, it got control structures and whatnot and it even got types which assembler certainly doesn't need.

But the language was designed decades ago. And since every boolean result gets down to individual bits in the processor's status word it obviously was sufficient to just using an integral data type for it. And it made the compiler probably a little less complex since you can omit some type checking (in later languages control structures *need* a boolean value, in C they just need an integral value of either 0 or something else).

Comment: Remember that early C also used `char*` before `void*` was standardized as the generic pointer type.  A processor had no notion of a `void`, so the language used the smallest-resolution data pointer that the hardware understood.  More "abstract" notions like `void*` came later.  C is a very close-to-the-metal language, and abstracting true/false into a new data type that is not reflective of something that hardware can uniquely understand didn't make much sense (a `bool` would simply be a `char` with additional limitations, simple enough to `typedef` yourself if you really need it).

Answer (score 11):

A CPU has no "boolean type", they only work on bytes and multiples of them so a boolean type made no sense at that time as it didn't give an advantage (why use a type when you can only check "is 0" or "is not null")

Comment: Sure the CPU has boolean types.  The flags register is stuffed with them!

Comment: Yes, but they are not general-purpose.

Answer (score 11):

It was common (and still is in some cases) to treat zero as false and any non-zero as true.  This has advantages for shorthand: for example, instead of `while (remaining != 0)` you can just use `while (remaining)`.

Some languages standardised on true being -1.  The reason for this is that in twos-complement notation (which most computers use to represent negative numbers), the bitwise-not of 0 is -1 (in 8-bit binary , `11111111` is decimal -1).

Over time it was realised that using a compiler-defined constant would prevent a lot of potential confusion.  It's been a while since I've done C++, but I'm fairly sure any non-zero value will still evaluate "true".

Comment: I always found the 0/-1 thing interesting when I first discovered it - especially since so many teachers/lecturers would incorrectly explain that positive 1 was `true`.

Comment: Positive 1 **is** "true" in C, in the sense that comparison operators and boolean and/or/not operators evaluate to 1 or 0 for true or false, respectively. But it's best not to think of true as having a value, since any nonzero value is true.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect it was deemed sufficient to have an integer type, with 0 being false and anything not 0 true.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Most booleans are handled as integers anyway when compiled to assember.

Answer (score 7):

The type you use to store a Boolean (usually) embodies a trade-off between space and time. You'll typically get the fastest results (at least for an individual operation) by using an int (typically four bytes). On the other hand, if you're using very many, it can make a lot more sense to use one byte or even pack them so each value you're storing uses only a single bit -- but when/if you do that, reading or writing a single bit becomes substantially more expensive (and uses extra code).

Since there was no one answer that was really "right", they left the decision to the user to make based on the requirements of the program they were writing.

The real question, then, is why a Boolean type was added in C99. My guess is that a couple of factors are involved. First, they realized that readability and convenience for the programmer is now usually more important than giving the absolute best performance possible. Second, compilers now do quite a bit more global analysis, so it's at least possible to guess that somebody *might* write a compiler that tries to pick a representation that's most appropriate for a particular program (though I don't know of any that really does).

Comment: +1: I liked the mention of space-time-tradeoff. Thats a very important point.

Comment: On some compilers, an `int` is the fastest format for storing a Boolean value.  On many (but not all), however, a `char` would be just as fast.  Some embedded-system processors have a special `bit` type which is faster yet (though such processors generally do not allow one to include `bit` types within other structures).  It would be silly to store a Boolean in an `int` on a platform where a `char` would be just as fast (or, for some embedded processors, even faster).

Comment: What supercat said, also, the initial target for c was generally very memory limited machines, you would nearly always prefer managing your bit-packing manually.  Adding a Boolean type back then would have encouraged what then would have been considered terrible machine code output.

Comment: @supercat There's still a minor code-size/performance penalty for having `_Bool`s over `char`s or `int`s as the integer data, where it previously didn't matter if it was 1 or 432 or any other non-0 valu, now has to be normalized into either `0` or `1`, at least where observable.

Comment: I would add that the love/hate step-child C++ already had a dedicated boolean type, and adding it was good for working together.

Answer (score 7):

Old C wasn't really "missing" a boolean type - it was just that all of the integral types were also considered suitable for doing doubly-duty, storing booleans.  I can see two main reasons for this:

- Bit-addressing processors weren't at all common (and still aren't), so the compiler wouldn't really be able to use a "true boolean" type to save any space - the boolean would still be at least as big as a `char` anyway (if you hoped to access it efficiently).
- Types narrower than `int` are widened to `int` in expressions anyway - so the boolean operators would still work on `int` operands.

..so it just looks like there wasn't a compelling enough case that a dedicated boolean type would actually convey practical benefits.

Remember that the C language does have a set of operators that produce boolean results (defined to be either 0 or 1) - `!`, `&&`, `||`, `!=`, `==`, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` - so it's only a dedicated boolean type that's not there.

Answer (score 5):

Historical reasons, probably:

CPL, which was heavily influenced by ALGOL, most likely had a boolean type, but my google-fu didn't suffice to find a reference for this. But CPL was too ambitious for its time, resulting in a stripped-down version called BCPL, which had the benefit that you could actually implement it on available hardware.

BCPL only had a single type - the 'word' - which was interpreted as false in boolean contexts if `0` and as true if `~0` (meaning the complement of `0`, which would represent the value `-1` if interpreted as signed twos-complement integer). The interpretation of any other value was implementation dependant.

After the still typeless successor B, C reintroduced a type system, but it was still heavily influenced by the typeless nature of its predecessors.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a separate "Boolean" type which isn't compatible with integers would have made the compiler more complicated than simply using integers for the purpose.  Having a separate Boolean type which is compatible with integers makes it necessary to specify the possible consequences of storing a value other than 0
or 1 into a Boolean object, or performing numeric computations on a Boolean
object whose representation contains neither the bit pattern associated with
"0" nor "1".  Given:

```
someBool = intFunction();
someInt = someBool;
```

requiring that someInt must receive the value 1 if intFunction returns any non-zero value would generally make the above more expensive than

```
someChar = intFunction();
someInt = someChar;
```

In cases where the former semantics would be required, they could be achieved without the use of a Boolean type, via:

```
someChar = !!intFunction();
someInt = someChar;
```

Since anything that can be done using Boolean types can also be done without them, and in many cases code which uses character types can be more efficient than Boolean types, I'd suggest that there never was (and still isn't) any real need for them.

Comment: Both yes and no. From the semantic point of view, `someBool = intFunction();` doesn't make much sense anyway, though apparently it's widely used idiom.

Comment: @ratijas: There are many functions which use an `int` return type to convey a 0 or 1 to the caller, either because they were designed before `_Bool` existed, or because they use the same return type for multiple purposes (e.g. an `int driverFunction(int functionCode, int param1, void *param2);`

Comment: yup. And that's the way C is. In some "higher-typed" languages you wouldn't use the same return type for multiple purposes. You would use separate types under union (possibly algebraic) instead — hence the _type_ system.

Comment: @ratijas: In situations where a function can perform multiple kinds of operations, selected via integer (a common situation with things like loadable device drivers that need to support multiple operations using a single entry point), it's often necessary to use a general-purpose combination of argument and return types for multiple purposes.  Conveying a true/false value via `int32_t` is more practical than using a `void*` to pass the address of a `_Bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Because they did not put one in. Sorry if that sounds snippish, but basically it was not defined as such.

Remember most people #define TRUE and FALSE.

You may say bool IS standard - but obviously it WAS not standard before C99 - which was made 10 years ago ;) They added it then when it became obvious a missing item.

Comment: +1: "Because they did not put one in."  The only possible answer.

Comment: It's standard not only in programming but also in thought process when solving a problem.

Comment: "Remember most people #define TRUE and FALSE" - they HAD to due to absence of any other method, so that's not really an answer to the why.

Answer (score 0):

Because none can foresee everything including missing data type in a programming language.