# Why are C booleans called _Bool?

Tags: c

Why does C use the word `_Bool` to define boolean values? Whereas they use the word `float` for floats and not `_Float`?

Furthermore, why does `bool` have to be included, why isn't part of the basic functionality, like `float`?

Comment: These are very good questions for a student. Don't be discouraged if anyone dismisses them.

Comment: A big part of this question is why the type was given the name `_Bool`; a quality answer should describe the problems that would have occurred with a name that may be used in existing code, and how the use of reserved identifiers may help avoid that problem.

Comment: Reopened. The question is about why `_Bool` is so named; not about "what is `_Bool`"

Comment: In my opinion, I don't understand why committee want this backward compatibly for such trivial thing. Always include `stdbool.h` is boring.

Comment: @Stargateur you would understand it if you ever had to work with a large code base already set up to use `bool` as typedef for a C89 type

Comment: Relevant reading for question two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374356/why-use-stdbool-h-instead-of-bool/47374416#47374416

Comment: @StoryTeller this thread is a dupe of that one tbh

Comment: @M.M - I'm torn. The answers are surely related. But the questions are vastly different.

Comment: @M.M update a code program to a higher version of the language require some work. Tool could easily be create to remove `typedef bool`. Keep legacy problem is the first problem of computer programming. People are afraid of change, python2 was a great exemple, there is still a lot of people who still code in python2 because they don't like change. That really sad, C99 was ten years after C89, it's clearly a major version but no don't do breaking change with `bool` (despise the fact that C99 made a lot of breaking change). If people don't want update their code, they should keep compile in C89.

Comment: "why does bool have to be included" --> To be clear, `<stdbool.h>` does not need to be included.  Code can use `_Bool` without the header file. `_Bool` is part of the basic functionality since C99.

Comment: I still don't understand why a boolean type is needed in C and I have never used it. Mybad? Has it caused more problems than it solved?

Comment: @WeatherVane Having a true boolean type allows you to substitute `if ( expression )` with `bool x = expression;  if ( x )` .  And other such transformations. Without a true boolean type this code fails for some expressions, you have to use hacks like `!!expression`.

Comment: @M.M if see no advantage with your `bool x = expression; if ( x )` over `int x = expression; if ( x )`. I have never needed to use `!!` hack. Or any trouble at all with `if ( expression )`.

Comment: @WeatherVane let's say `expression` is something that evaluates to `0x1000000000` (where int is 32-bit), your version will set `x` to `0` whereas the true bool version sets `x` to `1`

Comment: @M.M no, my version `int x = expression;` will set `x` to `0x1000000000`.

Comment: @WeatherVane that value is larger than INT_MAX, so `int` cannot hold it

Comment: Why down votes? This question is legit and can be considered as a good question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`_Bool` was not originally in C, but was added in the 1999 C Standard.  If it had been called `bool` then a large amount of existing code would break because many projects made their own type alias `bool` already.

The C89 standard set aside identifiers starting with `_` followed by upper-case character as reserved for implementation use. This is why new features added to C always start with such names. `_Complex`, `_Alignof` and `_Static_assert` are other examples.

There is also a header `<stdbool.h>` which aliases `bool` to `_Bool` and defines `true` and `false` ; this header can be included by new projects or by projects that didn't already define `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

C did not originally have a Boolean type, it was added in the 1999 version of the language (C99). At that point, C++ was already standardized (in 1998) to use the type `bool`, with keywords `false` and `true`. To keep the C Boolean type separate from the one in C++, as well as preventing the new name from breaking old C code, it was named `_Bool`.

The reason why it was named with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter, is because such an identifier was already guaranteed not to exist in compiler, library or user code, by 7.1.3:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

"Reserved for any use" meaning reserved for future versions of the C language.

Therefore, all new *language keywords* that have been added to the language since C99 are named with underscore followed by first letter upper-case. Other examples from C99 are the types `_Complex` and `_Imaginary`.

---

For the cases where code compatibility with C++ was desired, the header `<stdbool.h>` was created. It contains the macro `bool`, which expands to `_Bool`. And also the macros `false` and `true` that expand to `0` and `1`.

Though note that booleans are not fully integrated in the C language, as they are in C++. In C++, an expression such as `a == b` gives a result of type `bool`, with the value true or false. In C it gives a result of type `int`, with the value 1 or 0. This is for backwards-compatibility reasons with old C code.

Answer (score 1):

As for ...

> Furthermore, why does `bool` have to be included, why isn't part of the
>   basic functionality, like `float`?

... I observe that although you need to include `stdbool.h` to get `bool`, that's a convenience and C++-compatibility feature, not an essential.  `bool` is an alias for `_Bool`, and in C99 and later you have `_Bool` *automatically*, but even that is non-essential.  In C, any integer or pointer value can be interpreted as a boolean, with `0` or `NULL` being interpreted as false and all other values being interpreted as true.  This was how boolean values were handled in C from the beginning, and it still works in implementations conforming to the latest standard.

In fact, type `_Bool` itself is just a special case of this very behavior: it is an integer type whose minimal requirements are that it be able to represent the values 0 and 1.  In boolean context, it works just the same as any other integer type.

Comment: There's some cases where `_Bool` works different than integers. Most notably floating point conversions: `(_Bool)0.5` gives `1` while `(int)0.5` gives `0`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/icqtQ0